# Message sent using JMS producer is not received in MQTT receiver in the same SpringBoot app

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I'm just starting with ActiveMQ Artemis and have Artemis 2.17.0 installed on my machine. Created SpringBoot test app where both JMS and MQTT publishers and receivers exist. Created also small RestController so I can send messages using both JMS and MQTT producers. Receivers are quite simple and just create a log message to console. Now when I create a message using MQTT producer, both JMS and MQTT receivers get and log message to console. But when I send a message using JMS producer, the message is being received only in JMS receiver, no MQTT message in console. Tried several times. Implementation is ok I think as MQTT producer example is working fine. Is there any limitation for routing messages among protocols in Artemis in this way? Or what kind of problem it can be?

- Code info about JMS implementation: https://dmarko.tcl-digitrade.com/post/2021/activemq-artemis-spring-boot/
- Code info about MQTT implementation: https://dmarko.tcl-digitrade.com/post/2021/activemq-artemis-mqtt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis has a flexible [addressing model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html) that supports both Point-to-Point and Publish-Subscribe patterns.
By default, Spring Boot creates a JmsTemplate configured to transmit Point-to-Point while MQTT uses a Publish-Subscribe pattern, so the JMS and MQTT receivers are using different messaging patterns and this is causing your issue.

To configure a JmsTemplate for the Publish-Subscribe pattern set `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true` through Boot’s `application.properties` or set the JmsTemplate `pubSubDomain` to `true`, ie:

```
jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
```

To configure a JmsListener for the Publish-Subscribe pattern set `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true` through Boot’s `application.properties` or set the JmsListenerContainerFactory `pubSubDomain` to `true`, ie:

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${prices.mqtt.east}", containerFactory = "topicConnectionFactory")
public void receiveFromTopic(String message) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's working. At least partially. I set variable  application.properties and now MQQT is receiving the mesage produced by JMS, but JMS listener doesn't :-) Any idea what to do, JMS listener has following annotation: @JmsListener(destination = "${prices.mqtt.east}")

Comment: @DavidMarko I have update my answer to fix the name of the Boot'a application property `spring.jms.pub-sub-domain` and I have added an example with a JmsListener using a custom JmsListenerContainerFactory if the application property doesn't work for you.

Comment: This updated spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true done the right job. Now both JMS and MQTT listeners get the message. Thanks a lot for the insight.